# Adding image with Webpack and using it in sass

Tags: javascript, css, image, webpack, sass

I am new to Webpack and I am having issues loading images. I want to use Webpack to load images and to use this particular image in SASS as a background using background: url('./urlToMyPic.png');

```css
.home {
    background: url("../../Background2x.png");
    background-color: $dark;
    height: calc(100vh - 58px);
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```js
// entry --> output
const path = require('path');

//way to expose an object to another file
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /.\js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {}
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true //to allow client site routing
  }

};
```

Sass is working fine, Webpack is able to convert sass to css and to serve it properly. However, I am getting an error message when it comes to images:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loade/libloader.js!./src/styles/style.scss
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../Background2x.png' in '/Users/clement/Desktop/portfolio-react/src/styles'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/style.scss 8:507-540
     @ ./src/styles/style.scss
     @ ./src/app.js
     @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js
```

I can't figure out the problem ? Did any of you ran into a similar problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to define output filename for file-loader. If you don't do this, it won't keep the same filenames as in source:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
      publicPath: 'public/'
    }
  }
}
```

You can verify this by manually inspecting your public folder and checking image names.

Answer (score 0):

You can add publicPath to your output config.So the file loader can load images from the publicPath.

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  },
```